# How to host angular universal starter kit on IIS - Setting Client Server enironement

Tags: angular

I am trying to host angular universal project to IIS. i pointed a virtual directory to the dist folder. my dist folder has client and server folders inside
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEnZX.png). i tried to use IISnode for this. the app works but prerendering is not happening. please help.

Answer (score 0):

iisnode worked for me after much effort.  The trick for me was to run under regular node to see what errors I was getting, and that lead me to my problem.

In my case, I was using Angular Material which uses hammerjs which references window and document.  Those objects are not available serve side, so iisnode crashed out with an unhelpful error message.

For me, the issue was **hammerjs** which was used by **angular-material**

To solve, I updated my **tsconfig.app.json** like so

```
"types": ["hammerjs"]
```

and remove this line below from **app.module.ts**

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

In this way, the server side build doesn't have to deal with hammerjs but the client side build still gets the reference it needs.

Comment: Hi,In iis serverside rendering is not working for me.pls help me